# Can't get the right formula to set frame pts for a stream using libav

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat, pts

I'm trying to save a stream of frames as mp4.
Source framerate is not fixed and it stay in the range [15,30]

Encoder params:

```c
...
eCodec.time_base = AVRational(1,3000);
eCodec.framerate = AVRational(30, 1);
...
```

Stream params:

```c
eStream = avformat_new_stream(eFormat, null);                
eStream.codecpar = codecParams;
eStream.time_base = eCodec.time_base;
```

Decoder time_base is 0/1 and it marks each frame with a pts like:

```
480000
528000
576000
...
```

PTS(f) is always == PTS(f-1)+48000

Encoding (`dFrame` is the received frame, `micro` the elapsed time in microseconds):

```c
av_frame_copy(eFrame, dFrame);
eFrame.pts = micro*3/1000;
```

This make the video playing too fast.
I can't understand why, but changing `micro*3/1000` to `micro*3*4/1000` make the video play at the correct speed (checked against a clock after many minutes of varying fps)

What am I missing?

Comment: `eFrame.pts = micro*3/1000` is correct. According to the documentation in the comments of `AVRational time_base`: **"For fixed-fps content timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be identically 1"**. Are you using fixed-fps or variable fps?